# Regrouping the two code code insertion icons for clarity when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-interface, editor

As part of my interaction design studies, we analyzed Stack Overflow. Thereby I saw that many users mix up both icons used to insert code.

When they are asking to insert a runnable code snippet, they click first on the curly bracket.

In fact, how many users are aware that you can insert a runnable code in their question? And how they can make it?
(a quick search give you the answer though)

Here is the current view where the both code insertion icons are
[image]

and my proposal
[image]

I assume that users will be able to see these 2 different ways of inserting code at a glance. These two functionalities will moreover stick together.

Creating a group on the interface will encourage them to insert code, as this is an important feature when asking questions about programming.